# CSS vertical DIVs overlap each other (dynamic sizes, live example)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, grid, positioning

I got into a problem while working with ng-grid and dynamic sizes on window resize. I have a grid sample who resizes itself very well. No problem here. The window/elements sizes are configured as dymaic ones. At some point I need a summary of broken rules to appear below the grid. At the bottom of the page I have command buttons. Everything should have dynamic sizes. When I show the summary, it overlaps buttons. I tried min-height, but it didn't work. What I need is that when agreements div is too long, window scroll appears and no overlaps happen.

I have an example of what I am doing:

Any ideas? Please help.
http://plnkr.co/edit/dKcDeWcNt0baIDmMRJ7x?p=preview

```
  <div style="height:95%;border:2px solid blue; ">
  <div style="height:90%;border:2px solid green;">
      <div style="height:100%;border:2px solid pink;">
          <div style="border:1px solid red; height:80%;position:relative;">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0"></div>
          </div>
          <div id='yobaElem' style="display:none">
            ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>
            <textarea>Area</textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Summary" onclick="show()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason it says "must be accompanied by code" is because those who answer your question don't want to go to some other site to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your inner div(summery div) height:20% and overflow:scroll; so it will not overlap summery button.

```
<div style="height:95%;border:2px solid blue; ">
  <div style="height:90%;border:2px solid green;">
      <div style="height:100%;border:2px solid pink;">
          <div style="border:1px solid red; height:80%;position:relative;">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0"></div>
          </div>
          <div id='yobaElem' style="display:none;height:20%;overflow: scroll;">
            ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>ignore agreements
            <br/>
            <textarea>Area</textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Summary" onclick="show()" />
  </div>
</div>
```